# Python repeatedly causing a crash when executing daemons

Tags: python, workflow, plist, osx-mountain-lion

I'm not a programmer or anything like that, but I recently installed some python scripts and I'm struggling to execute them as part of a workflow on startup. I run an automator workflow that executes these three separate commands:

```
python /Applications/Sick-Beard/Sickbeard.py --daemon
python /Applications/CouchPotatoServer/CouchPotato.py --daemon
python /Applications/Headphones/Headphones.py --daemon
```

I can run these commands in a terminal window without any problem. However, when executing the commands as a single workflow or even three separate ones in quick succession, it always yields the follow error.

I'm at my wits end. Your help is very appreciated. The same error is caused when I create .plit LaunchAgents.

Thanks in advance, your help is more than appreciated. I had to put this on pastebin because I kept on getting formatting errors.

http://pastebin.com/qb65Mc53

Comment: Place code of your workers here, looks like all your workers using python's threads